# Resample vs class weights. Which is better?

Tags: machine-learning

I know there are two often used methods to handle imbalanced data in machine learning. One is use resample such as bootstrap (to make each class has same number of sample). The Other is balanced weight. I wonder which one is better for NLP or some other network models.

Comment: [When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning)

Comment: [What problem does oversampling, undersampling, and SMOTE solve?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285231/what-problem-does-oversampling-undersampling-and-smote-solve)

Comment: [What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem)

Comment: Statisticians do not see class imbalance as such a problem, and there is no need to use undersampling, oversampling, or artificial balancing to solve a non-problem. It might be helpful if you say why you find the imbalance problematic.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/558942/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: as often in machine learning.if the class size differs a lot. We will often have “same” guess. Moreover as shown in many Kaggle competitions. It will often give larger weight on minor class for balancing. For example https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/amex-default-prediction So I think it is really problem for imbalance data

Comment: If you’re predicting the same probability each time, you’ve probably made a programming error, and you should not apply a pseudo-statistical trick in place of debugging your code. And if you’re not using the probability values, what are you doing that’s giving you the same prediction every time?? // Have you read my links?